# STR_TO_DATE not working in my query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have date field in database having varchar datatype. Now I have to compare date with the current date but because of data type(varchar) result is not coming properly.

I don't want to change datatype in database so how can I query in codeigniter ?

In my **database** date is in this **format 30/11/2015**

**My current query:**

```
    //here vd is table field(one column).

    $cd = date('d/m/Y');//current date

    $this->db->where("date_format(STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') >",$cd); //comparing date with current date
    $query =$this->db->get('warranty');
```

> By using above query it is just comparing the date not month and year. So it is returning those record which date is greater than today's date.

But proper result is not coming....

Comment: no that's not a problem. I have written 'date' here only. but the field type is varchar instead of date so i can not compare date.

Comment: no it is 'PD' that means past date

Comment: may i use cast column in this query ? if yes then HOW ?

Comment: No need to use `cast` instead use `'str_to_date(PD,"%d-%m-%Y") >'`

Comment: thanks bro... it means my condition should be $this->db->where('str_to_date(PD,"%d-%m-%Y") >',$cd); ????

Comment: no sir it is not working

Comment: `echo` that query and try it within MySQL

Comment: when comparing dates both mySQL & PHP should have the data in the format %Y-%m-%d (I think) You cannot send 2 differently formatted dates & expect mysql to guess what you're sending correctly.

Comment: Use can better use DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: @ Uchiha any idea why it is not working ?

Comment: Which database are you using ??? many participants here try to guess your problem !!

Comment: what happen if you execute your query manually ?

Comment: it should return one row as per my database. But right now 0 record coming

Comment: I want those records which date(vd field) is greater than current date.

Comment: copy/paste for us a date stored in your database that it is greater then today... i can't see any error in your code :(

Comment: this is date of that record which should come 28/12/2015

Comment: yes in code there is no any error but result is not coming. And i can not change datatype of that column\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96555/discussion-between-halayem-anis-and-deep-parekh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this may be it will helps you :

```
$cd = date('Y-m-d');

$this->db->where("date_format(STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') >",$cd);
$query =$this->db->get('warranty');
```

You need to change date format if you use date_format in your query you are changing in same format may be that is the reason it is not working. try to change and compare in Y-m-d format.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check this query  manually. Then try to add it in `CodeIgniter`

```
$cd = date('d/m/Y');//current date

select * FROM warranty WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE($cd, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @DeepParekh Is there any record which fullfill such condition. Also executed manually?

Comment: yes in database there is one record which fulfill all conandition and i have double check that thing

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using two function to restructure the date format.

1. `date_format`
2. `STR_TO_DATE`

---

**Use `STR_TO_DATE`**

```
$now = date('d/m/Y'); //current date
$userdate = '2009-05-18 22:23:00'; //which get from user inputs

$dateModified = STR_TO_DATE($userdate,'%d/%m/%Y'); //output is 2009-05-18
```

So in function

```
$this->db->where('order_date >=', $dateModified);
$this->db->where('order_date <=', $now);
$query =$this->db->get('warranty');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('order_date BETWEEN '.$dateModified.' and '.$now);
```

> **This function will give you result of userSearch input and date to now. This function simply act like [*`between`*](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) in MySQL**

---

[image]

Comment: thanks but my prob is different. I don't have user input date. I just need to check with current date. but in database the date is stored with varchar data type so the result is not coming properly.

Comment: So your result wont come. change your database field as `DATETIME`

Comment: No i can't. coz so many data are in that table. so if I change datatype it will change the data(date field) to  0000-00-00

Comment: if you did this now then there is no harm. But when you hosted and online the project you have to think twice. **Not good idea at all**

Comment: get all data into CSV and clear db. Change type and import it. Game over

Comment: Just follow my method. you dnt ave any problem. try in your local

Comment: actually in that table the records are inserted by uploading file. so in file that date field format is fix in (d/m/Y) format and we can't change that. so i can not change the datatype of that field.

Comment: Actually now your DB don't know about what is month, What is year, What is date. So your code is not work at all

Comment: so what can i do now ?

Comment: drop you table data and change column type to DATETIME

Comment: no bro as i told i can not change datatype. coz those data are not coming from admin or by user input. Those data are coming by importing csv file. and in csv file date format is in d/m/Y so i cant change datatype it should be as it is varchar

Comment: You are doing it local . So no prob just try and see

Comment: i have tried already. but when i import csv the date field is coming like 0000-00-00 in all data. coz the format is changed. to d/m/Y to Y-m-d.

Comment: Before you import it refactor your CSV file. I have done this many times

Comment: but in future client will not refactor or change date field in csv. they will import as it.

Comment: So tell them the format. you are developer. they depends on u. So you have to guide them. Tell them what is format

Answer (score 1):

```
**Hope this may help you...**

$cd = date('d/m/Y');

$data['project'] = $this->common_model->selectRecord("SELECT * from project where project_date = '.$cd.'");

 in my project this is working ..
```

Comment: but in database date is stored with varchar datatype

Comment: $cd = date('d/m/Y');
$this->db->where(vd >,"$cd"); 
      $query =$this->db->get('warranty');

try this it it works

Comment: SELECT * FROM `warranty` where vd > 10/11/2015 . try this query in your MySQL

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `events` 
WHERE FORMAT( 
START ,  'DD/MM/YYYY' ) >  "25/11/2015"
LIMIT 0 , 30

i tried this and working fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96635/discussion-between-aakash-chandrakant-aware-and-deep-parekh).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$cd = date('d.m.Y');//current date

$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d.%m.%Y') >",$cd);
$query =$this->db->get('warranty');
```

To be sure that it comes out in the format you desire, use DATE_FORMAT:

```
$cd = date('d.m.Y');//current date

$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d.%m.%Y'),'%d.%m.%Y') >",$cd);
$query =$this->db->get('warranty');
```

Comment: Try using strtotime. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Error Number: 1305

FUNCTION tablename.strtotime does not exist

Comment: Sorry, just modified again.

Comment: try using FALSE as third parameter. I have modified answer.

Comment: it returning all records if i use false

Comment: Then you have to change your date(d.m.Y). means replace "/" with "." .I have modified answer

Comment: do i need to change in my db also ?? coz i have changed in query but same old result no any row coming.

Comment: Yes please. In database date is in this format 30.11.2015

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CAST ?

```
SELECT * FROM warranty WHERE CAST(vd AS DATE) ....;
```

Have you tried DATE ?

```
SELECT * FROM warranty WHERE DATE(vd) ....;
```

Comment: Your issue is really strange.. Could you export just warranty table and two or more lines ?

Just for trying on my local instance.

Comment: create table with just two field. vdate(varchar(25)) and id(int(11)). insert two three record. but date should be in d/m/Y (1/12/2015) format.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$this->db->where("date_format(STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') >",$cd);
```

To

```
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(vd, '%d/%m/%Y') > NOW()");
```